# Was the Gandhi in the Indira Gandhi name just a coincidence?

Tags: india, mahatma-gandhi

I found two theories regarding the "Gandhi" name in the Indira Gandhi family.

I haven't yet found credible sources for them. That is why I'm asking here.

The first is that

> Mohan Das Gandhi adopted Feroz Gandhi the husband of Indira Gandhi

The second being that:

> It was just a coincidence. Indira Gandhi's Husbands name happened to be "Feroz Gandhi" or "Feroz Gandhy" or "Feroz Ghandi".

Edit: Wikipedia says that "Firoz Ghandhy" changed his surname to "Feroz Gandhi"

If the second case is true please provide original spelling if possible.

If possible please suggest documents that I can obtain under Right to information to prove this.

https://www.quora.com/How-did-Indira-Feroz-Khan-become-Indira-Gandhi

https://www.answers.com/Q/How_did_indira_gandhi_get_the_name_gandhi

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feroze_Gandhi

Comment: "Original spelling" will not be in Latin letters?  So perhaps all of those spellings are merely alternate ways of transliteration.

Comment: Wikipedia cites: Lyon, Peter (2008) Conflict Between India and Pakistan: An Encyclopedia. Santa Barbara: ABC-CLIO. p. 64. ISBN 978-1576077122. "Feroze Gandhi was no relation of Mahatma Gandhi."

Comment: This question would be significantly improved if you could identify a notable claim to challenge.  A notable source for *either* of the two claims you're concerned with would do.